# Как заменить ссылки в модуле Joomla с помощью php из внешнего файла?

Tags: ссылки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В виджет, отображающий на сайте Инстаграм ленту из 6-ти последних постов, необходимо (как я пробую) при помощи php-кода вставить ссылки на эти посты, через атрибуты src= и href= как показано на скриншоте. Поскольку этот код виджета встроен на десяток сайтов, при добавлении новых постов в Инстаграм менять их url "ручками" на каждом сайте довольно геморройно) вот и хочу, реализовать их подмену из ОДНОГО .txt или .xls файла.

Как вариант, попробовал вышеуказанную комбинацию с подменой через указание php-переменных прямо в коде, но не вышло.. подскажите плз, как возможно реализовать эту задачу?

---

### Пробовали **вариант с созданием внешнего .php файла** с ID для этих шести insta-постов

```html
<?php
return [
    'id1' => 'sgsg4t3451',
    'id2' => '345341vfdA',
    'id3' => 'bfgw12aAvd',
    'id4' => 'ByLrLumiMVu',
    'id5' => 'ByJFfZ4Hrlp',
    'id6' => 'ByGXC_2HshD',
];
?>
```

со ссылкой на эти ID из HTML модуля Joomla:
[image]

но и в этом случае, сервер по-прежнему не обрабатывает php-запрос url выдавая ошибки:
так выглядит url

[image]

так выдает консоль

[image]

### Вопрос - **что делать? Как обойти шаблонизатор Joomla**, который, по-видимому и херит весь процесс.

Answer (score 0):

У вас всё должно работать, только.... Нельзя минус использовать в названиях переменных, так как он используется для арифметических операций. Замените `$INSTA_POST-1` на `$INSTA_POST_1` и будет вам хорошо)

Кстати, еще можно оптимизировать, делать время от времени запросы к API Instagram напрямую за постами. Обратитесь в лс если интересует.

Comment: Более развернутое решение было предложено здесь - https://toster.ru/q/676730 но пока также без результативно, к сожалению.

Comment: Глянул там.... Походу не обрабатывается PHP файл. Если это простой редактор шаблона, то может и не работать....